# What is the term used to describe a variable that refers to another variable?

Tags: terminology

When a variable is declared, there is one "step" between the variable and its value.

```
x = 'hi'
```

Depending on the complexity of the code, x may be referred to by other variables and arguments.  This can create many "steps" to get back to the original expression.

Is there a term for this phenomenon?  Long-chain-expressions?

Comment: I disagree with the first sentence. What is the definition of a "step?"

Comment: I'm not quite sure, hence the quotes around the word.  Any advice on how to improve the phrasing would be appreciated.  Perhaps "abstraction" or "references for evaluation"?

Answer (score 2):

Are you talking about a semantic expression (in which case, call it whatever you like, such as "recursive dereferencing"), or a programming term (in which case, the closest thing I can think of is "pointer")?

Comment: Either would be fine, as I'm a little confused on the terminology in general.  Thank you for making the distinction.  I suppose my question was "is there a name for pointers that point to other pointers, which point to other pointers...?"  I know it sounds stupid.  But I'm guessing there is a term for it in certain domains.  Perhaps when discussing shared state or locks?  No idea.

Comment: OK, to answer my own question, a pointer that points to another pointer is referred to as "multiple indirection".  Not sure if variable == pointer, or what a variable referencing another variable would be called.

Comment: Ah, my mistake, I think I misunderstood (hence "dereferencing", instead of "indirection"). It sounds like "indirection" is a better fit.

Answer (score 0):

Like roach374 said, I think 'Pointer' may be what you're after.

Answer (score 0):

In C++ are, additional to pointers, **references**.

A reference is similar to a *pointer* but with the guarantee that there is actually an object to access (a pointer, in comparison, can be NULL as well, thus, it might be necessary to check whether there is actually an object where it points to. Or it can be set to NULL by intention - not so a reference).

Is that what you are looking for?

Example (the reference is defined by the ampersand after the type):

```cpp
std::string original = "foo";

// Reference to the original variable
std::string& myRef = original;
cout << original << "  " << myRef << endl;

// Now change the original -> reference should follow since it's not a copy
original = "bar";
cout << original << "  " << myRef << endl;

// Reference to the reference
std::string& newRef = myRef;

// Again changing the original -> both ref's follow
original = "baz";
cout << original << "  " << myRef << "  " << newRef << endl;
```

The output would be:

```
foo  foo
bar  bar
baz  baz  baz
```